# erratic malformed expression and null.point.exception

Tags: java

I've got these two methods:

```
 private void PlaceAllPaddles(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println(" zoom zoom");
        paddleTop.SetCenter(this.GetMouseLocation());
        paddleBottom.SetCenter(this.GetMouseLocation());
        paddleLeft.SetCenter(this.GetMouseLocation());
        paddleRight.SetCenter(this.GetMouseLocation());

        paddleTop.Paint(g);
        paddleBottom.Paint(g);
        paddleLeft.Paint(g);
        paddleRight.Paint(g);
    }
```

which runs  *SetCenter* for *paddleTop* and *paddleBottom* properly but not for the other two. The difference between those objects lies in *String type* which for the bottom and top paddles contains "LEFTANDRIGHT" and for the other two "UPANDDOWN"

```
public void SetCenter(Point p){
        System.out.println(type+" x="+GetLocation().x+" y="+GetLocation().y);
        if("UPANDDOWN".equals(type)){

            SetLocation(new Point(GetLocation().x,p.y-(this.LENGTH_SEGMENT*this.size)/2));            
        }else{
            SetLocation(new Point(p.x-(this.LENGTH_SEGMENT*this.size)/2,GetLocation().y));
        }
    }
```

I've tried copying the line from the *else* instead of the line in the *if* body thinking that must be the problem but the effect was the same.

The program throws an error erratically. All I do is rebuild and run the program and sometimes it throws:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at four.Framed.PlaceAllPaddles(Framed.java:48)

Line 48 is

```
paddleLeft.SetCenter(this.GetMouseLocation());`
```

I added the two printed lines to try and locate the problem.

At other times it throws:

> zoom zoom LEFTANDRIGHT x=633 y=10 Exception in thread
>   "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   four.Framed.PlaceAllPaddles(Framed.java:47)

And sometimes it runs without errors (not too often):

```
>  zoom zoom 
>LEFTANDRIGHT x=633 y=10 
>LEFTANDRIGHT x=633 y=708 
>UPANDDOWN x=10 y=319 
>UPANDDOWN x=1336 y=319
```

When I run the program with the debugger, it throws no errors and seems to be doing everything correctly but when I hover over

```
GetLocation().x
```

or

```
GetLocation().y
```

it shows a tooltip with:

```
.x > Malform expression: "(ERROR)"<
```

yet it still prints:

> zoom zoom
>   LEFTANDRIGHT x=633 y=10

just fine.

The rest of the program runs fine if I don't call *PlaceAllPaddles* I'm not sure what is going on, why it's erratic nor where the problem may be at. Please help.

P.S. as requested, the GetLocation method:

```
public Point GetLocation(){
        return this.rectangles.get(this.size-1).GetLocation();
    }
```

the rectangles vector:

```
private Vector <Rect> rectangles;
which is set inside the constructor with the method:
private void MakePaddle(Point initLoc, String type){
        this.rectangles=new Vector<Rect>();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            Rect recti=new Rect();
            this.rectangles.add(recti);
        }
```

and Rect is a class I've made in another project and imported into the program:

```
public class Rect{
        private int x,y,width,height;
    private Color color;
    private Image image=null;

    public Rect(){

    }

        public void Paint(Graphics g){
        if(GetImage()!=null){            
            g.drawImage(GetImage(), GetLocation().x, GetLocation().y, null);

        }
        else{
            g.setColor(GetColor());
            g.fillRect(GetLocation().x, GetLocation().y, GetSize().x, GetSize().y);
        }
    }

        public void SetLocation(Point p){
        x=p.x;
        y=p.y;
    }
    public void SetSize(Point p){
        width=p.x;
        height=p.y;
    }
    public void SetColor(Color color){
        color=color;
    }
    public void SetTheImage(String str){
        image=SetImage(str);
    }
    public Point GetLocation(){
        return new Point(x,y);
    }
    public Point GetSize(){
        return new Point(width, height);
    }
    public Color GetColor(){
        return color;
    }
    public Image GetImage(){
        return image;
    }
    public boolean SetCollission(Rectangle r1){
        Rectangle r2=new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);        
        return r1.intersects(r2);
    }


    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for `GetLocation()`?

Comment: For this behavior "work sometimes" it means some kind of threaded services that didn't respond on proper timing therefore your NPE exception. Add the GetLocation code as @RC pointed out.

Comment: I've added the GetLocation code and other code it calls, maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem! The answer is actually not in the code I have posted. I have noticed an even stranger effect: When I was running an empty method it returned a NullPointException. I realized it had to mean that the object that contained the method was not initialized. The thing is I initialized all my objects in my frame's constructor. I then came to realize the problem lied in the fact that I extended my frame class from another Frame class I have made. The original Frame constructer ran first with the super command and only then were all of my objects initialized. Since I called the objects up in paintcomponent, it didn't recognize the objects because paintcomponent had started running as soon as the super command and original constructor ran. The reason it worked with the debugger, is that it was slow enough to allow the rest of the constructor to run simultaneously, initializing all objects.

thanks to all responses, nontheless.